# Eje secundario con ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Tengo los siguientes datos:

```
a <-data.frame(level=c(1,2,3),
               riesgo=c(1,1.321,1.783), 
               z=c(12427,8833,374))
```

Quiero que las variables "riesgo" y "z" estén representadas en el eje de las Y en función de level. Hasta ahora lo he podido hacer usando las funciones básicas de R:

```
barplot(a$riesgo, col="pink",ylab="RISK", xlab="level")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(a$z, type = "o", col="blue", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", ylab="")
axis(4)
```

Y lo que obtengo es el gráfico que quiero, aunque es muy poco elegante. ¿Cuál es la forma de hacerlo en ggplot, que me permita conservar la escala de Z?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En ggplot puedes poner un segundo eje Y, pero debe tener valores que sean un múltiplo del primero. Viendo los valores de las variables `riesgo` y `z`, he multiplicado el eje por 7000. Después, lo que hago es añadir el valor de z dividido por 7000.

```
ggplot(a) +
  # añado colunas
  geom_col(aes(seq_along(riesgo), riesgo), fill='pink') + 
  # añado eje Y secundario
  scale_y_continuous(
    "RISK",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*7000)
  ) +
  # añado linea Z
  geom_line(aes(x=seq_along(z), y=z/7000), col='blue') +
  # añado puntos sobre la linea Z
  geom_point(aes(x=seq_along(z), y=z/7000), col='blue')
```

Obtengo el siguiente gráfico
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias! una pregunta más: ¿Cómo le pongo nombre al eje de ese eje secundario? He intentado algunas cosas pero no he podido

Comment: Lo puedes indicar mediante el parámetro name dentro de sec.axis,
sec.axis = sec_axis(name = "Nombre", ~.*7000)